# Is there an alternative choice for cv::cuda::setTo()?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there an alternative choice for cv::cuda::setTo(Scalar, mask) or just cv::setTo(Scalar, mask)?I just met a problem when I use this:

```
buffer.conv_square.setTo(abs_threshold, buffer.buff, stream);
```

where the buffer is a struct for cv::cuda, all Mats in the buffer are GpuMats. buffer.conv_square and buffer.buff are CV_32 and abd_threshold is a float.

The problem is the mask buffer.buff can only be CV_8U, so I have to convert it from CV_32F to CV_8U. However when I do this

```
buffer.buff.convertTo(buffer.buff, CV_8U, 255);
```

I always get an error

```
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (unspecified launch failure) in cv::cudev::grid_transform_detail::TransformDispatcher<true, Policy>::call
```

Even, when I try the asynchronous call，the error is not shown again, but the next function will be an error.

Does anyone know how to fix that or avoid the problem by another function?

Answer (score 0):

For cv::cuda::setTo(Scalar, Mask) you can use the [Masked Set functions of npp](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/group__image__masked__set.html).

```
Npp32f val[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
NppiSize nis = { img.cols, img.rows };
nppiSet_32f_C3MR(val, img.ptr<Npp32f>(), static_cast<int>(img.step), nis, mask.ptr<Npp8u>(), static_cast<int>(mask.step));
```